# layouts using flex seems to be broken in latest chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2.2

My Chrome has just auto updated itself to 29.0.1547.57. Now all the layouts with flex config are broken. With Safari and with Sencha Architect's built in browser it's all good.

I wonder if I am the only one experiencing this.

Is there any quick solution? Do not want to downgrade Chrome...

Thanks

Comment: For those who are interested in the solution: <http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?269123-2.2.1-default-app.css-amp-chromium-blink-problem&p=987612&viewfull=1#post987612>

Comment: it happens to me on an application using dojo 1.6.1. aparently it's a blink issue..